# clojurescript: Trouble extending IAssociative assoc method

Tags: clojurescript

Ok, so I have two versions of a function here. One works, one doesn't. Code is based on the domina source; I'm expanding the same concept to google maps.
Working one:

```
(defn- create-listener-function
[f type]
(fn [evt]
  (f (reify
      ILookup
      (-lookup [o k]
         (if-let [val (aget evt k)]
           val
           (aget evt (name k))))
      (-lookup [o k not-found] (or (-lookup o k)
                                not-found))
      IAssociative
      (-assoc  [o k v]
         (aset o (name k) v))))
true))
```

Ok, so the above works fine, and I can lookup members of the returned object like so:

```
 (:latLng obj)
```

However, when I try to assoc something with the returned object, using the below code, I can no longer retrieve the object's properties.

```
  [f type]
  (fn [evt]
  (f (assoc (reify
             ILookup
             (-lookup [o k]
               (if-let [val (aget evt k)]
                 val
                 (aget evt (name k))))
             (-lookup [o k not-found] (or (-lookup o k)
                                         not-found))
             IAssociative
             (-assoc  [o k v]
               (aset o (name k) v)))
       :type type))
 true))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need to refer to the `IAssociative` protocol by its fully qualified name, `cljs.core.IAssociative`. In any case, the simplified example below works for me if I use the qualified name but not with the shorter name.

However, I found the same thing for ILookup, (I needed to use `cljs.core.ILookup`), so if that's working for you without the full name then I'm perhaps there's just something different about my or your setup.

```
cljs.user> (let [a (array 0 1 2 3)]
             (def obj
               (reify
                 cljs.core.IAssociative
                 (-assoc [_ k v]
                   (aset a k v)
                   (vec a)))))
nil
cljs.user> (assoc obj 0 'zero)
[zero 1 2 3]
cljs.user> (assoc obj 1 'one)
[zero one 2 3]
```